# log the Jboss connection pool count

Tags: jboss

I have a jboss-4.2.3.GA installation where I suspect the thread pool may be incrising  over time due to threads not being properly released. I am not getting any messages when maxthreads is reached, So I would like to log the number of threads in use to a file every five minutes so I can verify this hypothesis. Would anyone please be able to advise how this can be be done?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but someone might find this interesting. I had a similar problem where I wanted the monitor the jboss connection pools toward the database. What I did was to create a small shell script that each second minute used `curl` to fetch the relevant page from JBoss jmx-console.

I ended up using something like this in my `bash` script.

```
# Pools to check
POOLS="DefaultDS QuartzDS"

# Loop thru the pools and collect stats.
for pool in $POOLS;
do
    # Construct the URL
    url=http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean\&name=jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=$pool
    # Use 'curl' to fetch the web page, and awk to parse the output and put all rows with 'count' in them in a temp file.
    curl $url | awk 'BEGIN{RS="<td>MBean"}/Count/{print $0}' > _tmp_PoolStat.txt
    echo "Processing $pool"

    <process data in tmp file using your favourite tool.>
done
```

In your case you need to alter the `url` to match what you are looking for. Since I use a *nix based OS I ended up using `watch` to execute this script at a fixed interval.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JMX to get the thread count from java. 
with the addon jmx4perl you can do JMX calls from a very basic perl script. There is also an addon for Nagios to integrate with j4p for alerting and monitoring of various parameters.

http://blog.techstacks.com/2009/09/tomcat-management-jmx4perl-makes-it-easier.html has a few good examples.